# Less value function MySQL

Tags: mysql, function

I'm learning basic MYSQL and I want to get only the less value in this query.

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(HIRE_DATE,'%Y')      from employees;
```

Is there any function that do that?

EDIT:

I found the solution by myself. If someone wants to see is like that:

```
select MIN(timestampdiff(year,HIRE_DATE,CURDATE())) as LessYearsWorking FROM employees;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting the least you have a `least` function

```
mysql> select least(year(curdate()),year('2014-01-01')) as l;
+------+
| l    |
+------+
| 2014 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

And for getting the difference in years between 2 dates you can use [`timestampdiff`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

```
mysql> select timestampdiff(year,'2014-01-01',curdate()) as d ;
+------+
| d    |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Combining both of them and getting the difference and also the least value in the same query could be done as

```
select 
timestampdiff(year,'2014-01-01',curdate()) as d,
least(year(curdate()),year('2014-01-01')) as l ;
```

So your query becomes

```
select 
timestampdiff(year,HIRE_DATE,curdate()) as diff,
least(year(curdate()),year(HIRE_DATE)) as least_date
from employees
```

Comment: I tried but I'm doing something wrong, could you implement it there:   Select DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(HIRE_DATE,'%Y')      from employees;

Comment: Are you looking for a difference between 2 dates in year ?If so use `timestampdiff` function instead, check my update.

Comment: I already was doing that with the query that I've posted in the question, the problem is that I don't know how to compare (Like you did with timestampdiff) and get que lesser value at the same time.